# C# MVC - send file and data (not coming from a form) in a single AJAX call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I'm having trouble sending JSON data and a file through to my controller. I managed to get it to work with just `FormData` before (taking data from the form, which contains more than just the file input - but all data coming from the form). Now, in another flow I need to send the same file and data that does not come from the form.

This is my action:

```
public ActionResult Process(List<TheRequestClass> requests, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

And this is my latest attempt:

```
var data = // knockout.js-mapped data

var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(data);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('requests', JSON.stringify({ requests: unmapped }));
formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '@Url.Action("Process", "TheController")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (result) { },
    error: function (xhr) { }
    });
```

Unfortunately, in the controller requests end up as an empty collection, while the file does get uploaded correctly.

The raw data that I receive is:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryArn3v8KN5flwiB3k
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="requests"

{"requests":[ /* the array of requests */ ]}
------WebKitFormBoundaryArn3v8KN5flwiB3k
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="new_small test.xls"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

��ࡱ�
```

For comparison, the flow that worked (again - using only data from the form) was as follows.

Action:

```
public ActionResult Upload(OtherRequest request, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

AJAX call:

```
var formData = new FormData($('form#formId').get(0));

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Upload", "TheController")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) { },
    error: function (xhr) { }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove the `contentType`.

Comment: @Jai: that results in `Invalid JSON primitive: ------WebKitFormBoundary2uyG9boMUijj7Am0.` - fails immediately when trying to send the request, doesn't even get into the controller.

Comment: `FormData` is a collection of name/value pairs. You need to `.append()` each individual name/value pair to it (you cannot append a complex object). And since its a collection, it needs to be correctly indexed.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry, I don't follow. I though I am appending each individual name/value pair - one pair being requests, the other being the file? And what do you mean by indexing? Do you mean I should append each of the single requests separately?

Comment: You have a parameter `List<TheRequestClass>` so you need to append each property of `TheRequestClass` with indexers. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385587/formdata-append-item-in-array/43385767#43385767) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke I hate the fact that it works, because this means a lot of manual labor, since `TheRequestClass` is quite large and nested. Anyways, your solution does work - so if you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I'll just dupe it :)