# Issue deserializing an array of javascript object in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, deserialization, form-data

I have a problem deserializing a javascript array to c# List class, have read other answers on SO but did not solve my issue.

**The Array of Objects**

```
"{\"Id\":\"87\",\"Name\":\"Product x\",\"Cost\":200000,\"Tag\":\"Product_x\"},
 {\"Id\":\"88\",\"Name\":\"Product y\",\"Cost\":100000,\"Tag\":\"Product_y\"}"
```

The products are posted as FormData, so i receive them in the format above.

**Product Model**

```
public class Product {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Cost {get; set;}
    public string Tag {get; set;}
 }
```

**And i have a ViewModel**

```
public class ProductViewModel {
    [JsonProperty("SerializedProducts")]
        public string SerializedProducts{ get; set; } // So this model returns the array of objects above

    // Deserializes the SerializedProduct and converts to List of Products.
        public List<Product> Products
        {
            get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(SerializedProducts); } 
            set { }
        }
 }
```

**Error Message**
 Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List `1[Product]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

**What i observed**
 I expect SerializedProducts to return an array of object like this

```
"[{\"Id\":\"87\",\"Name\":\"Product x\",\"Cost\":200000,\"Tag\":\"Product_x\"},
 {\"Id\":\"88\",\"Name\":\"Product y\",\"Cost\":100000,\"Tag\":\"Product_y\"}]"
```

Please i need help. Thank you!

**Update**

**Javascript post**

```
function extractAndFormatFormData(formId) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var products = [];
    var product = new Product(Id, Name, Cost, Tag);

    // Add product to array
    products.push(JSON.stringify(product));

    // Add products to form
    formData.append('SerializedProducts', products);

    // I'm also attaching a txt file. This is not an issue at the moment
    formData.append('UploadedForm', uploadedFile);

    return formData;
}
```

## Ajax post

```
var formatedFormData = extractAndFormatFormData(formId);
        var url = '/Dashboard/provision/';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: formatedFormData,
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#planDetails').append(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

Comment: The "array of objects" isn't one, the JSON is invalid. To be an array, it would be within`[...]` (which you have in the example at the end). So if you're really receiving it without, add the square brackets.

Comment: Thank you @T.J. Crowder , this was what i suspected too. How can i fix it. i have updated my question to include the Form Posted. Can you help?

Comment: Looks like Cleiton's already sorted it out. :-)

Comment: O yes, great sir. Thank you too for pointing out the actual problem.

Comment: Suggest you also refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385587/formdata-append-item-in-array/43385767#43385767). Stringifying your data and sensdng it as FormData and then deserializing it again in a model property is unnecessary..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript, use stringfy on **products** array and not in item of array.

Code:

```
function extractAndFormatFormData(formId) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var products = [];
    var product = new Product(Id, Name, Cost, Tag);

    // Add product to array
    products.push(product);

    // Add products to form
    formData.append('SerializedProducts', JSON.stringify(products));

    // I'm also attaching a txt file. This is not an issue at the moment
    formData.append('UploadedForm', uploadedFile);

    return formData;
}
```